# User Online List PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to make a online user list output all my usernames in a row like this (username, username, username)
The code I'm trying:

```
        $result2 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `online`");
        $fetched2 = $result2->fetch_assoc();
        $user_id = $fetched2['user_id'];
        $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE id = $user_id");
        while ($fetched = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $users_arr[] = array("username"=> $fetched['username']);
        }
```

But it's only returning 1 username from online table and not all in a row, how can i do this?

```
return json_encode(array("status" => 200, "message" => $users_arr)));
```

This only outputted 1 username, and also it's outputted in json format which i do not want, i want it outputted like so: User, User, User and not like [{'username': 'vanilla'}]"

Can someone please show me the correct way of using an array or a solution to my problem, thanks!

UPDATE:

Tried this and it worked, but now the dilemma is how do i make the outputted json array to look like User, User instead of ['user1', 'user2']

```
    $users = array();
    $result = $db->query('SELECT user_id, ident, u.group_id FROM '.$db->prefix.'online LEFT JOIN '.$db->prefix.'users AS u ON (ident=u.username) WHERE idle=0 ORDER BY ident', true) or error('Unable to fetch online list', __FILE__, __LINE__, $db->error());


    while ($user_online = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $users[] = $user_online["ident"];
    }
```

I tried to use:

$trimmed = trim($users, '[]');

But this threw a warning/error:

```
PHP Warning:  trim() expects parameter 1 to be string
```

Also tried:

$string = implode('[]', $users);

It does output 2 users, but its formated/outputted like:
user1[]user2

Comment: Looks like your second query was unable to find any results for that specific `$user_id`. That's the only place you're setting the `$username` in the code you posted. Setting aside the glaring security issue with the way you're constructing the query (use prepared statements!), inspecting the query that's being executed will probably show you how `$user_id` isn't set the way you expect.

Comment: Are you sure its not cause the fetched result is in a while loop?

Comment: First see if the query is actually working. Output the SQL and inspect it. If it looks good, run it separately in your favorite MySQL client and double check the result.

Comment: How do i inspect it?

Comment: Make it a variable (like `$sql`) and then do `var_dump($sql);`.

Comment: Or just do `var_dump($user_id);` which is probably enough to show that the variable either isn't what you expect, or the whole query is wrong. I can't say anything about the latter without seeing your schema.

Comment: I fixed it (look my updated thread) but it's only returning 1 username, and not every username from online table in a row? How can i achieve this?

Comment: Store each `$fetched['username']` in an array and pass that through `json_encode()`.

Comment: Sorry, can you possibly show me how to do that? and i will forever be grateful.

Comment: The purpose of SO is to help you help yourself. I gave you everything you need to at least make a first attempt on your own. If you need help with whatever you're stuck at, then you can update your question and maybe we'll have another look.

Comment: I updated it @RoAchterberg

Comment: Drop the quotes around `"$users_arr "`.

Comment: Yea now it outputted "[{'username': 'vanilla'}]" how can i turn this into a prettier text? Like only the username

Comment: Also it still only shows 1 username... even with the array?

Comment: Your output is in JSON format. If you want to present it differently, then generally you do that in your view. Assuming you're using some kind of MVC architecture or variant thereof.

Comment: Yes but also, it's still only outputting 1 username and not all usernames?

Comment: Please update your question with the updated code as whole, not just the line you added.

Comment: Done @RoAchterberg

Comment: I fixed it @RoAchterberg but now i cant seem to trim it i've updated my thread can you please take a look?

Comment: Why did you delete the previous question. You haven't listened to any of the advice I have given you. You still have broken `$db->error()` and you are still not parameterizing the data. Why ask us for help if you don't listen to us and then remove questions. Please, respect us!

Comment: Cause @RoAchterberg told me to update my question...!

Answer (score 1):

*(Moved solution to answer space on behalf of the question author to move it from the question)*.

Fixed by using:

```
$string = implode(", ", $users);
```